# Shalom Aleichem in Kiddush Levana to an Aveil

Tags: halacha, minhag, mourning-aveilus, kiddush-levanah

We do not say Shalom Aleichem to a Aveil. What about saying Shalom Aleichem to an Aveil (after the Shiva, during the year of Aveilus) during Kiddush Levana - do you or do you not? (sources please)

Comment: Perhaps you should include why saying it could be forbidden?

Answer (score 8):

No.

> *Mourning in Halacha* 16:30 note 67a, citing *Shmiras Shabbos Kehilchasa* §65 note 163, citing R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach ZT"L